# HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath equivalent in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

What is the equivalent of `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` in .NET Core? I moved a project from ASP.NET to core, and a few Libraries are not included (Such as `System.Web`). Here is a small example:

```
sb.AppendLine("\"New Path\": \"" + newFile.FullName.Replace(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "/");
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`IWebHostEnvironment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment) interface provides information about the environment including the base path ([ContentRootPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.contentrootpath#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_ContentRootPath)). You can get an instance using dependency injection.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // env.ContentRootPath;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Previous version of this answer was using now obsolete [`IHostingEnvironment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment). Consider using it with `.net core` version `2.2` or earlier. Credit for pointing this out goes to [@Jack Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2484903/jack-miller).

Comment: I've already added an IHontingEnvironment element inside the class. So ContentRootPath will give me the same result as HttpRuntime,AppDomainPath?

Comment: `ContentRootPath` give the location set in `UseContentRoot` extension method in `Program.cs`. By default `UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`. So, it should give you the same result as `HttpRuntime,AppDomainPath`.

Comment: And what if i need the URL Path?

Comment: What if I need it in static constructor?

Comment: Initialize a static property in the `Configure` method. Then you can get the value of this property in the static constructor.

Comment: I get my C:/program/../../ result from this, and AppDomainAppPath gives me a path like /LM/W3C/<site id>/<servicename> what am i doing wrong?