# AppDomainAppId in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

When I get AppDomainAppId in .NET, I get a path like 
`/LM/W3C/<site id>/<servicename>`, how can I get the exact same path in an .NET Core service?

I tried the suggestion from [HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath equivalent in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916487/httpruntime-appdomainapppath-equivalent-in-asp-net-core) but I got my install path like `C:/path/to/app` and not a path as described above.

How can I get the path described above or how can I specifically get the `<site id>` part? I can get the `<servicename>` from `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName` but not the `<site id>` that I need.

Answer (score 1):

AppDomain is not included in dotnet core. Look at [Replacing AppDomain in .Net Core](http://www.michael-whelan.net/replacing-appdomain-in-dotnet-core/) for migration tips.

The path you get with .NET looks specific to the AppDomain implementation of ASP.NET. So I think you will not be able to get it with DNC.

---

In [System.Web/HttpRuntime.cs/Init](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRuntime.cs,4e4012af7843ff07,references), we can see `_appDomainAppId = GetAppDomainString(".appId");`

[`GetAppDomainString(string key)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRuntime.cs,b1038d89099749d6,references) calls `Thread.GetDomain().GetData(key);`. The `GetDomain` method is directly related to AppDomains. Those do not exist any more in DNC.

Comment: System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationID doesn't exist in .NET Core I think, I can use IHostingEnvironment in my Startup file Configure method, but HostingEnvironment has no ApplicationId.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it should work:

`DataProtectionUtilityExtensions.GetApplicationUniqueIdentifier(IServiceProvider)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.dataprotectionutilityextensions.getapplicationuniqueidentifier?view=aspnetcore-5.0

> The returned identifier should be stable for repeated runs of this same application on this machine. Additionally, the identifier is only unique within the scope of a single machine, e.g., two different applications on two different machines may return the same value.

This API is explicitly hidden for some reason. [Under the hood](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/DataProtectionUtilityExtensions.cs) it uses `IApplicationDiscriminator` which is also explicitly hidden and says it shouldn't be used publicly :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.infrastructure.iapplicationdiscriminator?view=aspnetcore-5.0

The [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/Internal/HostingApplicationDiscriminator.cs) is just based on the host environment `ContentRootPath` but perhaps there are other implementations when running on IIS, etc... which would return the same value as the old AppDomainAppId.