# Any way to get HttpRuntime from System.Web in .Net 6?

Tags: .net, .net-core

In .Net 4.8 app I have logic based on the value of the property (HttpRuntime from System.Web):

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId
```

Now I am trying to get this value in .Net 6 or Standard 2, but cannot find the way to reference HttpRuntime.. Looked through some Nuget packages for System.Web but none so far can do the job..

Or maybe if there is another place where AppDomainAppId is available?

Is this possible?

According to the answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891211/appdomainappid-in-net-core) question it's not, but trying my luck in case someone discovered the way..

Many Thanks

EDIT:

```
Public Shared Function GetLicensemanager() As ILicenseManager

            If HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId Is Nothing Then
                Return New LicenseManagerWin()
            ElseIf HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId.ToUpper.EndsWith("/WINAUTH")                    
                Return New LicenseManagerSingleSignOn()                        
            Else    
                Return New LicenseManagerWeb()                
            End If        
        End Function
```

Comment: Why do you want this? For logging purposes? Something else? `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId` is a low level implementation detail, and the implementation in .NET Core is not the same as .NET Old

Comment: The `Why` matters - whatever you want to do, there are other ways to do it that don't depend in a low-level detail.

Comment: OK, I get that.. But old logic in Net is based on that property.. Now I need to replicate that logic.. There is a factory class which creates Web, Win or SSO instance based on the value of this single property.. The joy of refactoring..

Comment: It's not refactoring. It's migrating to a completely different runtime. .NET Core isn't .NET Framework. SSO is provided by ASP.NET Identity which *doesn't* care about the app domain. Neither does ASP.NET Core Identity.

Comment: In any case, there is no AppDomain as a security context in .NET Core, so getting its ID is meaningless. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: OK, thanks.. Will need to rethink the approach here then..

Comment: The approach to what? SSO on Windows is provided by Windows itself. This works with web apps and can be transparent if the browser is properly configured. For cross-domain scenarios, federation and JWTs have become the norm. At the API level, an HTTP request comes with a set of Claims that may have come from a JWT token or any other mechanism. Instead of tying the identity to an app domain, the claims move along with the request

Comment: Please see the edit.. I was not clear enough I think, it's not SSO functionality, just factory creating three different instances of the class, with some properties, which differ among them..